# Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataContext Logging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, logging, sharepoint-2010, datacontext

I try to log SharePoint CAML queries of Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataContext to System.Console.Log.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataContext dataContext = new GeneraliETSPSDataContext(siteUrl);
dataContext.Log = System.Console.Out;
```

No success, no output in Visual Studio Output window.
I cannot start the debug from VS, I have to attach to w3wp.exe, sice the project is deployed to SPS to run.

Am I doing something wrong? Any tips on logging what DataContext does?

Answer (score 1):

Did you write any linq queries against the SharePoint Site?

something like:

```
var results = from r in datacontext.ListName where r.columncondition == true
```

Remember, LINQ queries are always executed when the query variable is iterated over, not when the query variable is created

The above query only gets executed when you iterate over the results or force it to execute by converting it into a list using results.ToList()

Depending on your actual requirement, there are several ways of logging datacontext queries or exceptions in general. You can log info to SharePoint ULS Logs, to a text file, to a SharePoint list(not recommended), or even to a document in a SharePoint library.

Comment: (Yes, I do wxecute the query.) To my knowledge, dataContext.Log = System.Console.Out; should log into Visual Studio Output window, when I debug the code. I have a new hint, since to debug SPS I attach to the w3wp.exe, maybe the System.Console.Out is set before the debugger starts, and output logging won't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

where do you want to log the actual output? System.Console.Out will just return a text writer to a non existant console.

If you want to log to the ULS logs in sharepoint you can do it very easily, here is a simple tutorial. http://blog.mastykarz.nl/logging-uls-sharepoint-2010/